# How to deploy server-client programs -java

Tags: java

After developing a server-client program how do you deploy so that all instances of the client program can connect to the server program across the internet?

Assuming I developed a multi client-server program which allowed clients to communicate with each other, all instances of these client programs would have to connect to the server program through ports across the internet so that the server program would distribute whatever messages they have to them.
Now my confusion is where do I put this server program in other to wait for connections from these client programs.

In the case of a database driven application, I would just have to upload my database to a remote server so that all instances of the application can connect to it.
but I am stuck for the case of the client-server program. please help.

Comment: We need a more specific description of problem

Comment: ok, tnx for replying. i want to develop a multi client-server program, meaning i would have to write a server program and a client program and then distribute the client program to users, now since these client programs would have to connect to the server program to work, where do i put the server program so that it can wait for connections from these clients.

Comment: It will depends on your application. Could be an application server like Weblogic or JBoss/WildFly, or a Servlet Container like tomcat. Maybe an embedded Tomcat, Jetty like Spring Boot does. How about client-server communication? Protocol?

Comment: and i was using a database driven program as an example, if i wanted instances of my program to communicate with each other through a database, i would have to upload my database to a remote server so that instances can access it across the internet. but when it comes to client-server programs i dont know how to go about it. if you think i am getting the whole concept wrong you can help me out.

Comment: @nyel the database itself is a server on your example. You have a running instance of the server  that will handle multiple clients requests. Your application need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You upload the server program to an application server - [JBOSS](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform), or other. The server can be hosted on your own machine, or a remote machine -it is up to you to decide. Clients will connect to the server and send requests there.

Comment: You are assuming that OP is asking about Java EE. The question might equally well be about a Java SE application (or some variation thereof - such as Spring Boot).

Comment: @tbsalling agree. I also think the question is related to software architecture in general not just Java.

Comment: thank you very much boss...i needed something like this. thanks

Comment: All you guys are right, the question is quite broad. My answer is one of many possibilities. 
I hope I made some sence and provided at least one sensible path to go about it.